# Placing icon file (.ico) for a VB 6.0 project

Tags: vb6, icons, basic

After assigning the icon to a vb6 form, does the .ico file needs to be present in the vb project folder? I tried deleting the icon file from the project folder and it did not have any effect on the form icon.

Comment: No. When you assign an icon its stored in the `formname.FRX` file in the project's directory.

Answer (score 1):

only if you load the icon specifically in your code

for example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Form1.Icon = LoadPicture("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Graphics\Icons\Traffic\TRFFC09.ICO")
End Sub
```

this will show the form with a trafficlight icon, but if you remove or rename the icon file, then running this code will through an error